# <h5>json sorted ascending order by value based</h5>

Tags: node.js, json, sorting, text

Here the Json data sorted:

```json
{ designer : 5, tester :8,developer : 10, backend :7 }
```

I would like to the following sorted order

```json
{ developer :10, tester :8, backend:7, designer :5 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to sort the properties of a json file? If the data is loaded into an object (like with `JSON.parse`[js], `decode_json`[php], `json.loads`[py]...) it won't matter the order in which they are laid out in the file. It looks like your data is not structured correctly for your need.

Comment: i need to display top 5 elements in json data

Comment: You should probably structure your data as an array, then. This way the items will already be in order when you load the json. When you are working with objects in javascript, the attributes doesn't have a particular order, so the order on which they exist in the json shouldn't be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sort JSON objects, we have to take help of Arrays. Arrays maintain an order of insertion. Moreover, it provides native sort() method to sort array elements.

Following sortByKey() function takes JSON Object as an input and returns JSON Array which is sorted by key.

```
var data = [
{ designer : 5, tester :8,developer : 10, backend :7 }
]

function sortByValue(jsObj){
  var sortedArray = [];
    for(var i in jsObj)
    {
      sortedArray.push([i,jsObj[i]]);
    }
    sortedArray.sort(function(k,v){ return k[1] - v[1]});
    sortedArray.reverse();
}

var jsObj = {};
jsObj.designer = 5
jsObj.tester = 8
jsObj.developer = 10
jsObj.backend = 7

var sortedbyValueJSONArray = sortByValue(jsObj);
console.table(sortedbyValueJSONArray);
```

We will create JSON Array of [jsonValue, jsonKey] from JSON Object. Then, we will sort JSON Array using sort() function. Checkout folllwing example.

```
------------------------------
|    0    | 10 | 'developer' |
|    1    | 5  | 'designer'  |
|    2    | 7  |  'backend'  |
|    3    | 8  |  'tester'   |
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the data is relevant for your case, you should use an array, not an object.

e.g.

```json
[
  { "name": "developer", "value": 10 },
  { "name": "tester", "value": 8 },
  { "name": "backend", "value": 7},
  { "name": "designer", "value": 5 }
]
```

Ordering the elements of the array is as simple as `JSON.parse(data).sort(({value: a}, {value: b}) => b - a)` (in JavaScript, ES6).